# PHP 2D array_diff / array_intersect for INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE

Tags: php, arrays, 2d

I have a pair of 2D arrays corresponding to a set of records from a database.

One array contains the current records, the other contains the new records.

I would like an elegant generic solution to sort these arrays so that I know which of the new records to INSERT or UPDATE, and which of the current records to DELETE. I'm sure this must be common behaviour, but an answer that doesn't require lots of nested array looping escapes me.

I think ideally a 2D array intersection would get the UPDATE records, and a 2D array_diff the INSERT / DELETE records.

Comment: share some code please. "A code snippet is worth a thousand words"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right I would suggest something like this:

```
$old_ids = array();
foreach ($old as $row) {
    $old_ids[$row['id']] = $row;
}
$new_ids = array();
foreach ($new as $row) {
    $new_ids[$row['id']] = $row;
}

$insert = array_diff_key($new_ids, $old_ids);
    //^^^Returns all records of $new_ids that aren't present in $old_ids
$update = array_intersect_key($new_ids, $old_ids);
    //^^^Returns all records of $new_ids that were present in $old_ids
$delete = array_diff_key($old_ids, $new_keys);
    //^^^Returns all records of $old_ids that aren't present in $new_ids
```

You now have 3 arrays with all data, and I think names clearly tell what to do with them. Just keep in mind that these functions return data of their **first** arguments, so

`array_intersect_key($new_ids, $old_ids) != array_intersect_key($old_ids, $new_ids)`

as `array_intersect_key($new_ids, $old_ids)` will return **new** data, and `array_intersect_key($old_ids, $new_ids)` will return **old** data, and you'll have to look up for new values again. Don't mess arguments order by mistake.

Comment: Thank you - yes this is effectively what I did. I think I was over thinking it on Friday! the only other addition would be to compare the intersect array with the old array to check the UPDATE was necessary.